# Initialise a lock/mutex safely inside a function

Tags: c, pthreads

**Scenario:** I want to provide a isolated foo in some foo.h/foo.c module. This function should be capable of executing in a thread-safe manner.

**Problem** How can I initialise a mutex (or any other lock abstraction) safely inside the function. I thought that I could have something like this:

```
foo(){
   static pthread_mutex_t *lock=NULL;
   if (lock == NULL){
     lock = init_lock(lock); 
   } 
   //acquire (lock)
   // foo ; 
   //release (lock)
}
```

But then i have to perform:

```
if (lock == NULL){
     lock = init_lock(lock); 
   }
```

atomically and I do not know how .

Comment: Why are you defining a pointer to mutex rather than a plain mutex with  a proper initializer?

Comment: because I need to check if lock was initialized or not . I know this is not the best ideia ever, and there must some common pattern to implement this but i am not being able to find one...

Comment: You wouldn't if you used a plain mutex with a proper initializer.

Comment: First, that should be `pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;` Second, what C are you using?, because I was not aware C (at least through 99) supported thread-safe static local initialization *regardless*. Maybe it does and I was asleep at the standard-wheel (again). I know C++ didn't get it until C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking too complicated

```
static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

is meant to do what you want to achieve.

If you just need the lock in that function place the static variable in there. If you need it in several functions, place it as global variable in the .c file.

Comment: Note that if you needed a recursive or error-checking mutex, or priority inheritance, robust mutex, process-shared mutex, or any other special attributes, this would not work. Instead, you would use `pthread_once` to initialize the mutex.